# Way to close video after finish using ExoPlayer

Tags: android, android-video-player, exoplayer

I'm basically trying to close a video once it has finished playing and return to the activity where the video was played from. I'm currently using an ExoPlayer and I know that my code needs to execute during the onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) with the playbackState being 5 (the code for the video being ended). I've tried doing several things such as player.stop() and player.release(), I've also looked at the demo project for ExoPlayer but cant see anything there either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this by calling finish() in the onPlayerStateChanged when the player state was 5 (which is the ended state). However the reason this didnt work before was due to my ExoPlayer not attaching the listeners.

```
public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
    for (Listener listener : mListeners) {
        listener.onStateChanged(playWhenReady,playbackState); //Gives access to closing the video
    }
}
```